# Motion of a charged particle in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

[image: Gyration]

In the image above, I'm following everything until the bit I've put in a red square. The force is expressed as the product of the mass and the rate of change of velocity, which is simply Newton's second law. What I don't understand is why taking the dot product of this with the velocity yields the bit in the red square. I understand that the bit in brackets is the particle's kinetic energy, but again I'm confused how the dot product in the previous step got us this result.

I'm sure I'm missing something super basic. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the equation backwards and consider the product rule for differentiation.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbf{v}^2
=\sum_i\frac{\mathrm{d}v_i^2}{\mathrm{d}t}
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_iv_i\frac{\mathrm{d}v_i}{\mathrm{d}t}
=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{v}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}.
\end{equation}

Comment: It's the power rule, and then the chain rule

Comment: That 1/2 factor in the summation is wrong

Comment: d/dt v^2 = 2v dv/dt

Comment: @jensenpaull so where does the factor of 1/2 come from in the original equation?

Comment: **1/2** m v^2 :)

Comment: D/dt 1/2 mv^2 = 1/2  m * (2v dv/dt)

Answer (score 2):

$$m. v.\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}m.(2v.\frac{dv}{dt}) $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}m.(\frac{dv^2}{dt}) = \frac{d}{dt} (\frac{mv^2}{2})$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

**[1]**$$m\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot v = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{mv^2}{2}\right) = 0$$ Which  can be written as power$$F \cdot v= \frac{dW}{dt}$$

Using the relationship for momentum $p=mv$, we can state that

**[2]** $$F \cdot v = \frac{dp}{dt}\cdot v = \frac{d(mv)}{dt}\cdot v$$

And as our velocity vector is identical, we can write from **[1]**$$m\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot v =m\frac{d(v\cdot v) }{dt}$$

Where

$$d(v\cdot v) = dv\cdot v\space + v\cdot dv = 2(v\cdot dv)$$ from the product rule, and thus

**[3]** $$(v\cdot dv)= \frac{1}{2}d(v\cdot v)$$

Now we have from **[2]** and **[3]**$$\frac{d(mv)}{dt}\cdot v  = m\frac{(v\cdot dv)}{dt}= \frac{1}{2}m\frac{d(v\cdot v)}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}m\frac{dv^2}{dt}$$

Which should give you your result with some rearranging $$\frac{1}{2}m\frac{dv^2}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{mv^2}{2}\right)$$